# how to feed data into my LSTM in correct shape and how to create labels for my dataset?

Tags: keras

I have  video dataset of violence situations and I converted every video to 7 images.
I used pretrained vgg16 to extract features from every image so I have my data set now as array of images
and every image is in the size of 7*7*512.
I worked on just 10 videos of my data set so I have features of (10*7 = 70) image so my array of features was in shape(70, 7, 7, 512).

so I reshaped my data to be like this concept (samples, time steps, features) I considered my samples as my videos, my time steps as the number of images from every video which is 7 images, and number of features is 7*7*512 = 25088 so I reshaped my input to (10,7,25088) and this is my code:

```
lstm_train_sample = np.reshape(x,(10,7,25088))
t_labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(LSTM(200, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(7, 25088)))
lstm.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
lstm.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
lstm.add(LSTM(25, activation='relu'))
lstm.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
lstm.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
lstm.add(Dense(2))
lstm.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
lstm.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',metrics=['accuracy'])
lstm.fit(lstm_train_sample , t_labels , epochs=150 , batch_size=2 )
```

so I have some questions:

1. the input shape is right like this?
2. the shape in the first layer right or wrong? (time steps, number of features)
3. I made the batch size = 2, I want to know the batch size here means that there is 2 videos for every batch or it means there is 2 images for every batch?
   in another way the batch size is dealing with the samples which is videos or dealing with time steps which is images?
4. I need to make labels for every video or sequence of images this means I need to have array of 10 labels cause I use 10 videos for train so how can I create labels for them in correct way that  makes the  LSTM deal with the labels as class not as integer value.

Answer (score 0):

1 - the input shape is right like this?

Yes.

2- the shape in the first layer right or wrong ? (time steps, number of features)

Yes, it's okay.

3 - I made the batch size = 2, I want to know the batch size here means that there are 2 videos for every batch or it means there are 2 images for every batch ? in another way the batch size is dealing with the samples which is videos or dealing with time steps which are images?

batch_size = 2, meaning 2 data points will be passed in a batch that means 2 videos, not images. You're in batch data dimension will be (2, 7, 25088)

4 - I need to make labels for every video or sequence of images this means I need to have an array of 10 labels cause I use 10 videos for the train so how can I create labels for them incorrect way that makes the LSTM deal with the labels as a class, not as an integer value.

Your labels must be one-hot encoded. You can use `tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical`

Comment: great, don't forget to upvote/accept answer if it helps.